# asterisk peer with SIP provider through proxy

Tags: voip, asterisk, sip

I'm trying to make a asterisk server connect to a SIP provider (which offers PSTN origination and termination). I've been reading the great [Definitive Guide](http://www.asteriskdocs.org), but it doesn't seem to cover the case where the provider is contacted through a proxy. The [sip.conf documentation](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/index.php?page_id=78) mentions the `outboundproxy` field, but I'm not having much success with it.

Here's my current sip.conf:

```
[general]
context=unauthenticated         ; default context for incoming calls
allowguest=no                   ; disable unauthenticated calls
srvlookup=yes                   ; enabled DNS SRV record lookup on outbound calls
udpbindaddr=0.0.0.0             ; listen for UDP requests on all interfaces
tcpenable=no                    ; disable TCP support
outboundproxy = proxy.voip.sapo.pt
outboundproxyport= 5070
register => +351000000000:password@voip.sapo.pt/line1


[sapo]
type = peer
host = voip.sapo.pt
; Most providers won't authenticate when they send calls to you,
; so you need this line to just accept their calls.
insecure = invite
dtmfmode = rfc2833
username = +351000000000
secret = password
context = incoming
```

I'm not sure if the host (on the peer section) should be the proxy or the original server. Same for the register line.

All I'm getting from the console is timeouts:

```
 Reloading SIP
       > doing dnsmgr_lookup for 'voip.sapo.pt'
[Dec  7 14:48:30] NOTICE[5192]: chan_sip.c:11722 sip_reg_timeout:    -- Registration for '+351000000000@voip.sapo.pt' timed out, trying again
```

Answer (score 1):

I would change your register command to register to: `proxy.voip.sapo.pt:5070`.

Comment: Ah, so the register must be done on the proxy? Doing that change, I'm getting a `handle_response_register: Got 404 Not found on SIP register to service +351000000000@proxy.voip.sapo.pt, giving up` now. Analyzing the traffic, it seems it is doing a `REGISTER sip:proxy.voip.sapo.pt`, while another (successful) sip client does `REGISTER sip:voip.sapo.pt` (to proxy.voip.sapo.pt)...

Comment: `register => +351000000000@voip.sapo.pt:password@proxy.voip.sapo.pt:5070/line1` seems to take care of that. Now there's just a `Failed to authenticate on REGISTER`. I'll phone my provider to try and troubleshoot this one